# Play! Framework 2.1.1 and Google Closure - SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I want to use Simple Optimization from Google Closure in Play! (using Scala)

I searched a while now for solutions to do that.

First thing I found is to put following in Build.scala:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  closureCompilerOptions += "advancedOptimizations"
)
```

But somehow the advanced Optimizer is killing my JS completely. It even "optimizes" document.getElementsByTagName() to a.a()...

So I searched a little bit more and found another approach:

```
val defaultOptions = new CompilerOptions()
defaultOptions.closurePass = false
CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(defaultOptions)
defaultOptions.setProcessCommonJSModules(false)
defaultOptions.setManageClosureDependencies(false)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  closureCompilerSettings(defaultOptions) : _* // ++
)
```

This is doing exactly what a want, but with a big down side, which is a no-go in my case. It combines all Javascript files.

Does anybody has a Idea how I can disable the JS merge? It doesn't do the merge in the first approach, only for the second. And I don't have a clue why.

Comment: It looks to me like the default externs aren't being included. But I don't know how you would change that using Play!.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth do you now how do I include externs within Java API? Maybe with this I could get the AdvancedOptimization working.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html